# discord.py guilds.members not working correctly

Tags: python, discord.py

It works, but for some reason not on all servers, but on certain ones. I understand that it can't get the server members because it is trying to create a DM for itself.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(guild.members)
        for member in guild.members:
            guild.fetch_members()
            print(member)
            try:
                await member.create_dm()
                await member.send(text)
            except:
                print('direct messages are closed')
                await asyncio.sleep(25)
                continue
```

I tried Googling, I just found that I need intents, I tried nothing has changed. Here they are if anything:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, members=True, typing = True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Comment: Have you tried `await guild.fetch_members()`?

Comment: I tried everything so it doesn't work. I inserted in try

Comment: Are you using a self-bot?

Comment: yes,I use a self-contained bot

Comment: Self-bots are no longer supported and against the ToS.

Comment: Hey! I used to have that issue. In: `for member in guild.member`, change the `member` to any thing else, like `person`. That fixed that for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent some time looking through the discord.py docs and I think I may have found the issue. When you run `guild.fetch_members()` inside of that `for`, it seems like you're attempting to enable access to members in `guild.members`. Though this may work sometimes, the documentation recommends a different usage which is likely more reliable and which is possibly newer.

From the [fetch_members() docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members) (a bit paraphrased):

#### Example Usage:

```py
async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=150):
    print(member.name)
    

# if a discord.ClientException is raised, the members intent is not enabled.
```

Let me know if this helps/works

Comment: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access

Comment: hmmm... seems like it might be an issue with some other part of your bot? could you maybe add a link to the full code to your post so I could take a look? (disclude the discord token obviously)